# getting html page when trying to access reviewboard diff using rest api

Tags: review, review-board, rbtools

Here is a code review on reviewboard  and I was trying to access the diff via rest api.

```
curl https://reviews.reviewboard.org/api/3184/diff/7/ -H "Accept: application/json"
```

but this is always giving me a html page.

I tried this and

```
curl --insecure https://reviews.reviewboard.org/api/3184/diff/7/ -H "Accept: application/json"
```

it returned me  json result but get message object does not exists. not sure what that means !?

{"err": {"code": 100, "msg": "Object does not exist"}, "stat": "fail"}